# Как правильно организовать ооп поиска анкет?

Tags: php, ооп, объекты

Модель поиска **oSearch** -> возвращает массив анкет с информацией о каждой из них. Как правильно организовать представление полученных данных?

Когда речь была о модели пользователя **oUser**, её передавал в представление, а в нем просто запросы данных типа *oUser->getName()*

При поиске модель возвращает массив данных и передавать его крутить в представлении.. Так все делают?

Comment: Не по теме, но: общее мнение по поводу венгерской нотации в текущий момент - лучше не использовать, скорее вредит чем помогает.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Когда речь была о модели пользователя oUser, её передавал в представление, а в нем просто запросы данных типа oUser->getName()
>
> При поиске модель возвращает массив данных и передавать его крутить в представлении.. Так все делают?

Нет, так никто не делает. Если у вас есть модель, то из поиска должна возвращаться коллекция (в контексте PHP - просто массив) моделей, возможно, пустая.

Если вы делаете это все руками, и массив получаете руками тоже, то следует задуматься о выборе фреймворка или хотя бы ручном прикручивании доктрины.

Comment: в представление нужно передавать массив/коллекцию моделей, правильно понимаю?

Comment: Да, только не на уровне представления, а уже из компонента поиска должна появляться коллекция.